# android simple facebook returns "Canceled by user" when publishing post

Tags: android-simple-facebook

I have configured android simple facebook library for my app.
It's working properly, but the problem is when using `mSimpleFacebook.publish(feed, true, onPublishListener)`, it always fails with error "canceled by user".

```java
Permission[] permissions = new Permission[] {
   Permission.EMAIL,
   Permission.PUBLIC_PROFILE,
   Permission.PUBLISH_ACTION
};
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

Thanks

Comment: Have you followed https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook#usage?